# Native library working incorrectly on some JVMs

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I'm trying to use a native library in java using JNA. The library loads, and I can call methods, but on some JVM distributions the native library does not behave as expected. Some results:

```
JDK distributions              Behaves as expected
Oracle JDK 1.8.0_191           yes
Liberica JDK 1.8u192           no
Liberica JDK 1.8u275           no
AdoptOpenJDK OpenJ9 1.8u272    yes
AdoptOpenJDK OpenJ9 15.0.1     no
AdoptOpenJDK Hotspot 1.8u275   no
AdoptOpenJDK Hotspot 14.0.1    no
```

Here expected bahaviour is getting getting hardware info via `LC_get_hardware_info` and then exiting without errors.

No JDK9+ distributions seems to work, some JDK8 distributions work, some don't (edit) all tested JVMs are 64-bit.

The code (edit: not calling `LC_get_hardware_info` does not change behaviour, just there's no output in case of success), values returned by `SenseLC` are error codes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    SenseLC lib = SenseLC.INSTANCE;

    PointerByReference handle = new PointerByReference(new Memory(8));
    
    int ret = lib.LC_open(0, 0, handle);
    if (ret != SenseLC.LC_SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("Open: " + SenseLCUtil.getCodeName(ret));
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Handle: " + handle.getValue());

    LC_hardware_info hi = new LC_hardware_info();
    ret = lib.LC_get_hardware_info(handle.getValue(), hi);
    if (ret != SenseLC.LC_SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("Read: " + SenseLCUtil.getCodeName(ret));
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(hi);

    ret = lib.LC_close(handle.getValue());
    if (ret != SenseLC.LC_SUCCESS) {
        System.out.println("Close: " + SenseLCUtil.getCodeName(ret));
        return;
    }

}
```

`SenseLCUtil.getCodeName` just maps return codes to strings

Expected bahavior:

All calls to `SenseLC` return `0` (`LC_SUCCESS`), after invoking `ret = lib.LC_get_hardware_info(handle.getValue(), hi);`, `System.out.println(hi);` prints:

```
LC_hardware_info{
developerNumber={somenumber}
serialNumber={somenumber}
setDate={somenumber}
reservation=0
}
```

Failure behaviour:

Invoking `int ret = lib.LC_open(0, 0, handle);` is successfull (`ret=0` after call), then after running `ret = lib.LC_get_hardware_info(handle.getValue(), hi);` `ret=3` (`LC_INVALID_PARAMETER`), and the program output is:

```
Read: LC_INVALID_PARAMETER
```

It seems as if an incorrect handle is returned from native code on some JDKs.

**Edit 1**: added LC_hardware_info and SenseLC classes

LC_hardware_info:

```
@FieldOrder({
    "developerNumber",
    "serialNumber",
    "setDate",
    "reservation"
})
public class LC_hardware_info extends Structure {

    public int developerNumber;
    public byte[] serialNumber = new byte[8];
    public int setDate;
    public Pointer reservation;

    public String getSerial() {
        return new String(serialNumber, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LC_hardware_info{"
            + "\ndeveloperNumber=" + developerNumber
            + "\nserialNumber=" + getSerial()
            + "\nsetDate=" + setDate
            + "\nreservation=" + reservation
            + "\n}";
    }

}
```

SenseLC:

```
public interface SenseLC extends Library {
 
    int LC_SUCCESS = 0; // Successful
    int LC_OPEN_DEVICE_FAILED = 1; // Open device failed
    int LC_FIND_DEVICE_FAILED = 2; // No matching device was found
 
    int LC_INVALID_PARAMETER = 3; // Parameter Error
    int LC_INVALID_BLOCK_NUMBER = 4; // Block Error
    int LC_HARDWARE_COMMUNICATE_ERROR = 5; // Communication error with hardware
    int LC_INVALID_PASSWORD = 6; // Invalid Password
    int LC_ACCESS_DENIED = 7; // No privileges
    int LC_ALREADY_OPENED = 8; // Device is open
    int LC_ALLOCATE_MEMORY_FAILED = 9; // Allocate memory failed
    int LC_INVALID_UPDATE_PACKAGE = 10; // Invalid update package
    int LC_SYN_ERROR = 11; // thread Synchronization error
    int LC_OTHER_ERROR = 12; // Other unknown exceptions
 
    SenseLC INSTANCE = (SenseLC) Native.load("Sense_LC", SenseLC.class);
 
    int LC_open(int vendor, int index, PointerByReference handle);
    int LC_close(Pointer handle);
    int LC_passwd(Pointer handle, int type, byte[] passwd);
    int LC_read(Pointer handle, int block, byte[] buffer);
    int LC_write(Pointer handle, int block, byte[] buffer);
    int LC_encrypt(Pointer handle, byte[] plaintext, byte[] ciphertext);
    int LC_decrypt(Pointer handle, byte[] ciphertext, byte[] plaintext);
    int LC_set_passwd(Pointer handle, int type, byte[] passwd, int retries);
    int LC_change_passwd(Pointer handle, int type, byte[] oldpasswd, byte[] newpasswd);
    int LC_get_hardware_info(Pointer handle, LC_hardware_info info);
    int LC_get_software_info(LC_software_info info);
    int LC_Hmac(Pointer handle, byte[] text, int textlen, byte[] digest);
    int LC_Hmac_software(byte[] text, int textlen, byte[] key, byte[] digest);
    int LC_update(Pointer handle, byte[] buffer);
    int LC_set_key(Pointer handle, int type, byte[] key);
    int LC_gen_update_pkg(byte[] serial, int block, byte[] buffer, byte[] key, byte[] uptPkg);
 
}
```

**Edit 2** library header :
[lc.h](https://pastebin.com/WQymdrEQ), part of the [sdk (Clave2)](https://www.senselock.it/dongle/en/content/6-download)

**Edit 3**:
Updated JNA mappings, problem persist. Old code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/bcjHN509)

Comment: Can you include the code that instantiates `SenseLC.INSTANCE`?  Also I don't see where the expected output is being generated, is the above code a helper method?

Comment: Can you also post the `LC_hardware_info` (which I assume is a structure?) as that's almost certainly the actual problem.

Comment: @stridecolossus I added the relevant clases, but it shouldn't be an LC_hardware_info issue, just running open and close one after another has the same behaviour

Comment: So the code fails when you invoke the close method, even if you don't invoke any other native methods?  In that case I'm wondering whether the handle should be a JNA `IntegerByReference` rather than an array?  But we'd need to see the native header to be sure - can you post that as well?  Is it a custom project or something available on t'interweb somewhere?

Comment: @stridecolossus I also tried int[], IntByReference and LongByReference with no changes to behaviour

Comment: @sarunas Very odd, the only thing I can think of is how the `lc_handle_t` is being mapped on each JVM, from the header file it looks like there are two `typedef` declarations for the handle depending on the architecture, i.e. on 64-bit it will (probably) be a `long` as you mapped it but on 32-bit platforms it's a native `int`?  I don't have any experience with the JVMs you are trying so that's just a guess.  Perhaps you can run a quick test with the handle fiddled to an `int` for one of failing JVMs?

Comment: @stridecolossus seems the handle only uses 4 bytes, don't know what that means. Tried to check if handle byte order or endianeness is wrong somehow, simply casting long to int, no effect.

Comment: @sarunas I don't think casting on the Java side will work.  If the handle is 4 bytes then its a native `int` and I suspect you will need to change the JNA mappings from `long` to `int`.

Comment: As @stridecolossus says, the problem is almost definitely your mapping of the handle type.  Have you considered using `handle_t extends PointerType` as a mapping?

Comment: Did you compile the native DLL on the same machine you're running it?

Comment: @DanielWiddis I'll try the handle_t mapping, the dll comes precompiled without source.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are getting differing results on different JVMs is indicative of undefined behavior.  In the cases where it's appearing to work, you're just getting lucky.

As has been discussed in the comments, your problem is likely the mapping of the `lc_handle_t`.  The header file indicates it's a pointer size on 64-bit machines, and `int` size on 32-bit machines.  So you should use `PointerByReference` when you see `* lc_handle_t` (when opening to get the handle) and then use `getValue()` on that returned handle for the other uses of the `lc_handle_t`.

That type also appears in the `reservation` field of your `LC_hardware_info` structure, which should be mapped to `Pointer`.

Comment: Loading 32-bit DLLs on 64-bit JVMs fails with `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: <lib> : Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`, so I'm sure the DLL is 64-bit.
I edited my source to use `PointerByReference handle = new PointerByReference(new Memory(8))` instead of `int[] handle = new int[1]`, that didn't have any impact on bahaviour on different jvms. My updated source [on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/muUrpz1s)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `lib.LC_get_hardware_info(handle.getValue(), hi);` is using `getValue()`.

Comment: The pastebin (from first comment to this answer) is up-to-date. From the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801123/native-library-working-incorrectly-on-some-jvms/64828042?noredirect=1#comment114706485_64828042) I thought you were talking about line 102 if the pastebin.
Also, should I update the question with code changes or keep it as is?

Comment: My apologies, bouncing between the 3 different references has gotten me confused.  Regarding updating your question, yes it's fine (and preferred) to add information to your question, although editing it in such a way that an answer no longer makes sense (e.g., fixing the error in the original code) tends to be confusing. Leaving the original code but updating with "Here it is now, still produces this output: XX" is very useful.

Comment: I've deleted my comments that are no longer relevant to keep this thread clean.  At this point I can't see anything wrong with your mappings.   Can you provide more details on what "expected" yes or no means? What exact calls give what errors/values?  Are the return values from the API error codes?

Comment: All methods return error codes, so expected behavior is all methods return `0` (`LC_SUCCESS `) and `LC_get_hardware_info` fills the given `LC_hardware_info` with data. I updated the question with more details.